# Transferring Source code from NetBeans to JGrasp

Tags: java

I'm trying to transfer code but I keep running into encoding errors and binary set errors when I try to transfer the source code from NetBeans to JGrasp.

Comment: Post your code...be specific...

Answer (score 0):

If you use "File" > "Open" to open files in jGRASP, you can specify the encoding on the open dialog (if you double click, drag-and-drop, etc. it will use the system default encoding).